# How to use pagination on queries in Hibernate with Java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

This is my hibernate configuration:

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(final DataSource dataSource,
            final Environment env)
    {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("...");

        final Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

Now I want to make a query in HQL (using `@Query(value = "query")`) with standard pagination settings like offset and limit. I know about `query.setMaxResults()` and `query.setFirstResult()`, but for that I need a `Session` (or do I?), but I didn't use sessions to configure Hibernate.

Can I use annotations only to specify the offset and limit to queries? Is there a way to use HQL to programmatically simulate `query.setMaxResults()` and `query.setFirstResult()`?

Comment: Sprind data manages hibernate session behind the scene. You can get an hibernateTemplate to excecute manual queries if you want but since Spring data provides pagination queries why don't you use it?

Comment: @akuma8 You mean `Page` and  `PageRequest` objects?

Comment: Yes, is also there the interface `PagingAndSortingRepository<T,ID>` that your repository can implement to enable paging and sorting.

Comment: @akuma8 Thanks, will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code may help you.

```
public Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable){
    //custom page
    PageRequest customPageable = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), 100);
    return productRepository.findAll(customPageable);     
}
```